# How to reset a single patch hard in git add interactive mode?

Tags: git

I'm often using `git add --interactive` in patch mode after trying different working and non-working things to create multiple commits (comments about the non-working and effective code about the working things). To create those commits I go through the set of patches interactively several times and there're some patches which I'd like to drop, i.e. neither add to the current nor to one of the following commits. If I have to go through the patch set a lot of time, I always have to make the decision to leave the patch out instead of making it disappear once like I'd do with `git reset --hard HEAD -- [path]` for a file.

Is there a way to acchieve this optimization?

Example:

```
> git add --interactive --patch
diff --git a/file b/file
index 3652a25..296f68d 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
 abc

-def
+123

 ghi
+
+456
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,s,e,?]? s
Split into 2 hunks.
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 abc

-def
+123

 ghi
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,/,j,J,g,e,?]? n
@@ -4,2 +4,4 @@

 ghi
+
+456
```

Here, I don't want to see replacement of `def` with `123` in any further calls of `git add --interactive` and be able to add, skip and split all other patches as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git checkout -p [file]` :

much like `git add -p`, it will run in interactive mode, and ask you for each individual diff chunk on `[file]` if you want to keep it as is or revert it.

Comment: Yes, this way I can run through the changes once and discard all patches that I don't want and then run `git add -i`.